# Ghost (nonexistent) votes in reputation tab

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

<sup>*Unfortunately I have recently received some upvotes, which means that new bugz are uncovered...*</sup>

**TL;DR**: if there's a day, on which you receive upvotes on post, then you check reputation tab and after some time receive upvotes on the *same* post again, rep tab tells you wrong amount of new rep gain (**ONLY in the "time" mode**)

---

Reputation tab shows everything correctly if there aren't any new reputation changes since the last time you have visited the rep tab. Otherwise, there could be *problems*.

I'll give you a couple of examples based on my reputation history for **March, 30** (that's yesterday, yeah).

1. Let's [visit my reputation tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259214/nicael?tab=reputation&sort=time), select the "time" mode and check March, 30. Here's what you will see:

   [image: Image showing correct reputation details in the "Time" view]

   There're 5 upvotes and 1 downvote for the post about topbar.
2. Now *let's assume* that the last time [you have visited the tab, it was March 30, 20:00 UTC on the clock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259214/nicael?tab=reputation&StartDate=2022-03-30%2020:00:00Z&sort=time). You can click this link, since I know how to use a time machine and hence it's repro'able.

   [image: Image showing ghost (non-existent) votes in the "Time" view; for example, the image shows 70 rep instead of 40 for the post about topbar on 31st March]

   Oh wow, how cool is that? So how many upvotes have I got in total?

**Conclusion**: if there're some reputation changes that you haven't seen yet, the time tab shows them wrong. I prefer using the time tab sometimes, since it highlights the unseen rep changes with yellow which allows you to check how many votes ago I checked it.

Comment: Nothing new here, has been for ages like this. There must be a dupe somewhere out there.

Comment: @Luuklag It seems all the reports about this gets closed as duplicates of this question. [Here's one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378170/reputation-gain-history-incorrect) that got the [tag:status-norepro] tag, but with the detailed information in **this** answer I hope that we'll see the [tag:status-reproduced] tag on it.

Comment: @ted meme: possible duplicate of nicael’s report. Cultural height: right in the duplicate banner

Comment: For what it’s worth: [I can reproduce this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIu01.jpg). It seems that any post that got more than one vote during that day shows an inflated total count.

Comment: I can confirm I see this or something like it regularly, have done for the past ... what ... month or so? But for me it's on the Post tab. I'll go there, see +50 on a post, but going to the post shows it has a score of 20 (and no downvotes). Happens often enough I'm fairly certain it's not just people reversing their upvotes in a hurry. :-D