# Reputation gain history incorrect

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation

[image: Incorrect reputation time]

It somehow shows I had a +170 reputation gain 4 hours ago, as part of my +70 rep gained so far today. It should be +50 based on the total.

The issue only happens to the highlighted new/recent rep changes. You can force it by passing a [start in the query string](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/22772/andrew?tab=reputation&StartDate=2022-04-15%2020:00:00Z&sort=time).

Comment: Huh... I don't see +170 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgVrh.png I've seen a few reports about the numbers on the rep history page being off but I can't duplicate this one. Do you still see it?

Comment: @Catija I now see what your screenshot looks like. Perhaps this is a bug that only applies to rep marked recent/since last visit to the rep page, or perhaps when it combined the two upvote lines from 4 hours and 34 minutes ago into one summary line it fixed the issue? It's a pretty minor but it did happen and still needed a report.

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure what's going on here - being transient (or only related to recently-earned reputation) and fixing itself on refresh would make it lower priority but still something we should look into.

Comment: Yeah, I reported that already. You could compare “time” with “post” tabs. “post” shows everything correctly

Comment: @Catija reproducible [if you provide a startDate query string](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/22772/andrew?tab=reputation&StartDate=2022-04-15%2020:00:00Z&sort=time) so it looks like the issue has to do with entries marked as new specifically

Comment: @Yaakov bunch of people claim they can reproduce it, it's better explained in the dupe, did you take a look on it as well?

Comment: @Yaakov A bug that has very specific conditions, that are laid out in this and the dupe, is far from non reproducible, just takes more work to do it, particularly when there's a link in the comments here. Minor issue but needs proper investigation.

Comment: @Andrew agreed, and if the meaning is to dismiss the bug, [tag:status-declined] would be fair.

Comment: I've hit this a few times, but it does seem to go away on refresh: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz1Ch.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RgQP.png