# Incorrect stats sometimes showing up. Is this a bug?

Tags: bug, profile-page

Sometimes I see some odd stats but then I blink (click something) and everything looks good again so I haven't manage to catch it in the act. However, now I did.

What caught my eye this time was the stats on the reputation page. 100 + 30 = 60.
[image]

It was actually `100` that made me react, since that answer had only received 4 upvotes and the other had received 2 and 40 + 20 = 60. That makes sense. This time I opened another window and left the strange looking one be - and I then saw the correct stats:

[image]
(no votes on my answers came in or was withdrawn between the image snapshots)

Bug?

Comment: @Laurel Perhaps it does. I'm not entirely sure and can't judge if that's the case. It doesn't have any answers that can help me to decide either. If this question gets closed as a duplicate, I'll accept that it's the same issue.

Comment: @Laurel I've tried finding a duplicate tagged with one of the [moderator tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144959/409219), like one of the `status-` tags that would indicate that they have looked at this issue, but unfortunately I couldn't find one. Since the issue seems to be common knowledge I find that a bit surprising..

Comment: There is one tagged no-repro, but it seems to be a real bug - 3rd report this past month: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378170/786798

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Ah, thanks! I didn't find that one. [tag:status-norepro] doesn't sound promising :-)

Comment: Yeah, I had a bit of trouble finding it too - we (as a community) kind of goofed with choosing the one that does not have employees weighing in as the canonical for this problem.