# Reputation lost due to "User was removed" differs dependent on selected subtab in reputation history

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, reputation-history

I lost some reputation today because a user was deleted, which happens quite often. However, the amount of reputation lost changes between the 'Post' and 'Time' tabs in the Reputation tab. 'Post' says 50:

[image]

while 'Time' says 130:

[image]

I have enough reputation to not really care about the actual amount; I do care about the inconsistency. According to [my answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312191/295232), -50 is correct. What happened?

Comment: Probably related to/same as https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377620/ghost-nonexistent-votes-in-reputation-tab, where it is also reported that the Time tab shows incorrect reputation changes (on unseen/yellow lines only) while the Post tab is correct.